# nested structure into an assembly file using masm compiler

Tags: assembly, nested, structure, masm

Does someone know how to create nested structures in assembly using the windows compiler ml.exe

I would like to declare the structure of startupinfoexa (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-startupinfoexa) but it contains the structure startupinfoa (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa)

The startupinfoa structure is declared like this in my code:

```
STARTUPINFOA    struct 
cb            DWORD    ?
lpReserved    DWORD    ?
lpDesktop     DWORD    ?
lpTitle       DWORD    ?
dwX           DWORD    ?
dwY           DWORD    ?
dwXSize       DWORD    ?
dwYSize       DWORD    ?
dwXCountChars    DWORD    ?
dwYCountChars    DWORD    ?
dwFillAttribute  DWORD    ?
dwFlags       DWORD    ?
wShowWindow   WORD    ?
cbReserved2   WORD    ?
lpReserved2   DWORD    ?
hStdInput     DWORD    ?
hStdOutput    DWORD    ?
hStdError     DWORD    ?
STARTUPINFOA    ends
```

And it works well, but now i would like to use in my code the startupinfoexa, but i don't really know how to declare it as it contains the startupinfoa structure. What i used below doesn't work:

```
STARTUPINFOEXA struct
StartupInfo     STARTUPINFOA ?
lpAttributeList DWORD ?
STARTUPINFOEXA ends
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it with angle brackets:

```
STARTUPINFOEXA struct
    StartupInfo     STARTUPINFOA <>
    lpAttributeList DWORD ?
STARTUPINFOEXA ends
```

Example (the program performs a `"cmd /cDIR"` in a console):

```
.686
.MODEL FLAT

CreateProcessA PROTO STDCALL :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD
WaitForSingleObject PROTO STDCALL :DWORD,:DWORD
ExitProcess PROTO STDCALL :DWORD
puts PROTO C :DWORD
fflush PROTO C :DWORD
_getch PROTO C

INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib
INCLUDELIB msvcrt.lib

STARTUPINFOA    struct
    cb            DWORD    ?
    lpReserved    DWORD    ?
    lpDesktop     DWORD    ?
    lpTitle       DWORD    ?
    dwX           DWORD    ?
    dwY           DWORD    ?
    dwXSize       DWORD    ?
    dwYSize       DWORD    ?
    dwXCountChars    DWORD    ?
    dwYCountChars    DWORD    ?
    dwFillAttribute  DWORD    ?
    dwFlags       DWORD    ?
    wShowWindow   WORD    ?
    cbReserved2   WORD    ?
    lpReserved2   DWORD    ?
    hStdInput     DWORD    ?
    hStdOutput    DWORD    ?
    hStdError     DWORD    ?
STARTUPINFOA ENDS

STARTUPINFOEXA struct
    StartupInfo     STARTUPINFOA <>
    lpAttributeList DWORD ?
STARTUPINFOEXA ends

PROCESS_INFORMATION STRUCT              ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms684873.aspx
    hProcess        DWORD ?
    hThread         DWORD ?
    dwProcessId     DWORD  ?
    dwThreadId      DWORD  ?
PROCESS_INFORMATION ENDS

.DATA
    app db "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe",0
    arg db "/c dir", 0
    msg db 10,10,"ok",10,0
    startinfoex STARTUPINFOEXA <>
    procinfo PROCESS_INFORMATION <>

.CODE

_start:

    mov startinfoex.StartupInfo.cb, sizeof (STARTUPINFOEXA)

    ; CreateProcess(app,arg,0,0,false,0,0,0,&startupinfo,&procinfo)
    push OFFSET procinfo
    push OFFSET startinfoex
    push 0
    push 0
    push 0
    push 0
    push 0
    push 0
    push OFFSET arg
    push OFFSET app
    call CreateProcessA         ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx

    ; WaitForSingleObject( procinfo.hProcess, INFINITE );
    push -1         ; INFINITE
    push dword ptr [procinfo.hProcess]
    call WaitForSingleObject

    ; puts ("ok"), fflush to flush the stdout-buffer
    push OFFSET msg
    call puts
    mov dword ptr [esp], 0
    call fflush
    add esp, 4

    call _getch             ; Stop and wait for a key pressed.

    ; return 0
    push 0
    call ExitProcess

END _start
```

Comment: Just what I want ^^